# Creating new input fields via dropdown, how to limit new inputs to just 1 each?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, append

so I have a select dropdown which creates 2 new input fields.

**My jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/CbcmS/

[image]

The problem I'm having is after you create a new input field you could keep on creating the same input field over and over again. Just keep choosing each selection over and over again in [the dropdown](http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/CbcmS/).

[image]

**This is not intended, what I would like to have happen is once an input has been created, you can't create anymore.**

My only thoughts at the moment are creating another variable which would store cell phone or work phone into an Array or just a true false boolean and check against that in the if else statement.

However would you know of an easier or more straight forward way to accomplish this?

*jQuery:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var cellphone = "<th><label>Cell Phone:</label></th><td><input type='tel' name='cp' value=' ' maxlength='11' /></td>";
var workphone = "<th><label>Work Phone:</label></th><td><input type='tel' name='wp' value=' ' maxlength='11' /></td>";

$('#id_contact_info').change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == 2) {
            console.log('cell phone');
            $('.choice_cell_phone').append(cellphone);

        } else if ($(this).val() == 3) {
           console.log('work phone');
           $('.choice_work_phone').append(workphone);
        }

    });

});
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="form-fields">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="id_contact_info">Add More Contact Info: </label></th>
        <td>
            <select name="contact_info" id="id_contact_info">
                <option value="1">select contact type</option>
                <option value="2">Cell Phone</option>
                <option value="3">Work Phone</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="choice_cell_phone">

    </tr>

    <tr class="choice_work_phone">

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Just disable that option in the select once it's been created!

Comment: Oh like some kind of remove from select function?

Comment: I think a nice way to do this would be to use the .html() method instead of append, so: $('.choice_cell_phone').html(cellphone); and $('.choice_work_phone').html(workphone); This way you don't need to use an extra variable as a flag to see if they've been added or not.

Comment: In your `change` event, include this line: `$(this).find("option:selected").prop("disabled", true)`. After you select this option, you can no longer select it again, it'll be disabled. @Leon -- Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CbcmS/24/

Comment: Sweet thanks! Using that in the project

Comment: @Leon please don't post an answer as an update to your code... sorry -- if you _want_ to post an answer, post it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the work/cellphone to jQuery objects: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/CbcmS/22/

```
var cellphone = $("<th><label>Cell Phone:</label></th><td><input type='tel' name='cp' value=' ' maxlength='11' /></td>");
var workphone = $("<th><label>Work Phone:</label></th><td><input type='tel' name='wp' value=' ' maxlength='11' /></td>");
```

Comment: No problem ^_^ happy to help @Leon

Comment: And assuming you will want to add more select options to that drop down, I would use a switch case statement instead of 'if else if'. Forked Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/Za5NL/

Comment: Oh yeah defs! That is what I should have gone with at first, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If what i understand right, you don't want to the `input` to be doubled. Why don't you use `html` instead of `append`? Change

```
$('.choice_cell_phone').append(cellphone);
```

to

```
$('.choice_cell_phone').html(cellphone);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/WHUqH/

Note : This wouldn't be that effective if you need to keep the data someone's typed in the text box, before *accidentally* clicking on the drop down. The best way would be to

1. Hide the particular option after its been added
2. Add a remove button next to the added input
3. show the option in dropdown if remove is clicked.

Comment: Can't have a cellphone and a workphone then, they'll keep over-writing one another.

Comment: @tymeJV how so? both seem to have different `tr`s set to them - `choice_work_phone` and `choice_cell_phone`

Comment: This also works thanks! Super clean :) though I think Neal's is even smaller

Answer (score 1):

This works. I made a new variable to check if the new input is deployed.

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nbnfF/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cellextra = 0;
    var workextra = 0;

    var cellphone = "<th><label>Cell Phone:</label></th><td><input type='tel' name='cp' value=' ' maxlength='11' /></td>";
    var workphone = "<th><label>Work Phone:</label></th><td><input type='tel' name='wp' value=' ' maxlength='11' /></td>";

    $('#id_contact_info').change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() == 2 && cellextra == 0) {
            console.log('cell phone');
            $('.choice_cell_phone').append(cellphone);
            cellextra = 1;

        } else if ($(this).val() == 3 && workextra == 0) {
            console.log('work phone');
            $('.choice_work_phone').append(workphone);
            workextra = 1;

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: I think he wants to replace the existing input if one exists.

Comment: Thanks this works! Though I think Neal's answer may be the most basic

Comment: @Leon, sure :) That's probably why he has 57.2k :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add an extra condition

```
if ($('input[type=tel]').length < 2) {
```

This will check for the length of the input and only pass when it's length is less than 2.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/CbcmS/23/)**

Comment: He would also need to replace the existing child if one exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your `<tr>`s already have children or not, changing your conditions to:

```
if ($(this).val() == 2 && $('.choice_cell_phone').children().length == 0) {
    //
} else if ($(this).val() == 3 && $('.choice_work_phone').children().length == 0) {
```

[**<kbd>JSFiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/KM6tK/)

Answer (score 1):

Basically all you need to do is check to see if the input already exists on the page when you check the val of the select. I also changed your equivalence to triple equals, but that is irrelevant to the solution here; it is just better practice because of the way JavaScript evaluates equivalence.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hApx3/

```
$('#id_contact_info').change(function(){

        if (($(this).val() === '2') && !$('.choice_cell_phone').children().length) {
            console.log('cell phone');
            $('.choice_cell_phone').append(cellphone);

        } else if (($(this).val() === '3') && !$('.choice_work_phone').children().length) {
           console.log('work phone');
           $('.choice_work_phone').append(workphone);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep appending the cellphone and work choices to a `tr`. What you need to to create a new `tr` for each option you're creating.